# Передача массива в функцию и range-based цикл

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, c++11

Весь мозг поломал, перечитал все об указателях и так и не понял как сделать этот код работоспособным. Как прямо сказать циклу что я ему подсовываю именно массив (а то он ругается что не найдена функция begin)?

```
void func (int * a)
{
     for (auto n : a) { std::cout << n; }   
}

int main() {

    int arr[] = { 4,7,3,4,7,8,9,0};
    func(arr);
}
```

Comment: связанные вопросы: [Range based for loop in function which passes an array as value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31824323/4279) и [Range based for-loop on array passed to non-main function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26182907/4279)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Поскольку вы передаете указатель (да даже если бы вы передали массив без указания размера - все равно передался бы указатель), таким образом - никак. Указатель не несет в себе никакой информации, кроме адреса. `func` никак не может узнать, где конец массива.
Поскольку в вопросе именно **range-based цикл**, то тривиальную передачу указателя, количества элементов и обычный цикл не рассматриваем.
Но и тут можно выкрутиться - с помощью шаблонов:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void func(T (&a)[N])
{
     for (auto n : a) { std::cout << n << " "; }
}

int main() {

    int arr[] = { 4,7,3,4,7,8,9,0};
    func(arr);
}
```

Comment: Изящно, большое спасибо!

Comment: PS Там еще получается бонусом идет автоматом передача размера массива в функцию, вообще красота. :)

Comment: Если уж шаблон, то можно написать короче: `template<typename T> void func(T&a)` - заодно обеспечим поддержку стандартных контейнеров.

Comment: @Chorkov Да, но тогда в нее можно будет передать все, что угодно, и сообщения об ошибке будут более запутывающими - типа, что не найден begin() для int. В моем варианте будет ругаться на невозможность инстанцировать.

Comment: Ну, если вопрос решен - закрывайте, отмечая ответ как принятый...

Answer (score 4):

@Harry. Стоит отметить, что в Вашем, очень изящном решении, в функцию передается не указатель на массив (как в исходном вопросе), а ссылка на массив известного размера. Именно такую рекомендацию дает Страуструп в четвертом издании своей книги (12.2.2, page 318):

> If you really want to pass an array, rather than a container or a pointer to the first element of an array, you can declare a parameter of type **reference to array**.

Если не использовать шаблоны, то получим набор перегруженных функций - по одной на каждый размер передаваемого массива (и каждого типа массива). В предложенном же решении размер массива, передаваемого в функцию, будет известен в результате выполнения процедуры конкретизации (instantiation) шаблона функции.

Comment: Ну да, я же и написал, что передача указателя не даст такой возможности - узнать размер массива...

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы произвольные коллекции, а не только массивы в range-циклы передать, можно template-функцию использовать:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Range>
void func(Range&& range)
{
  for(auto&& v : range) { std::cout << v; }
}

int main() {
  int arr[] = { 4,7,3,4,7,8,9,0};
  func(arr);
}
```

Пример:

```
$ make CXX='g++ -std=c++11' main && ./main
g++ -std=c++11     main.cc   -o main
47347890
```

See [C++11: Defining Function With Container Parameter (like range-based for)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13548339/4279)